# add double quotes in string using android

Tags: android, string, concatenation

I have string in forloop, I want add that in to another string like the given format

```
for (int i = 0; i < profiles.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = profiles.getJSONObject(i);
    String admnno   = c.getString(TAG_ADMNNO);
}
```

The result should be like this

```
"Rajesh", "Mahesh", "Vijayakumar"
or 
final CharSequence[] items = {"Rajesh", "Mahesh", "Vijayakumar"};
```

The adminno should be in double quotes and following comma. Its in android doin Background()

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `\"` for this

**For example** `String str="\"Rajesh\""`

Comment: mentioned within documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/characters.html  Ctrl + F "double quotation mark"

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(string))
        return "";

final int lastPos = string.length() - 1;
if (lastPos < 0 || (string.charAt(0) == '"' && string.charAt(lastPos) == '"'))
        return string;


        return "\"" + string + "\"";
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use Kotlin's multiline strings. Especially useful when you need hardcode big JSON for UTests:

```
val jsonString = """
  {
     "string_key": "value",
     "boolean_key": true
  }
  """
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
var id =  "\"id\": \""
```

Output =   "id": "

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quote using \" like below:

```
public static String getQuotedString(String sample){
      return "\"".concat(sample).concat("\"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, you can use a variable value like this way

```
val searchText = "Android"
textview.text = "5 articles found for \"$searchText\""
```

For fixed string:

```
String str="5 articles found for \"IOS\" "
```

value is equal for

> 5 articles found for "IOS"